# IIS 7.5 website reads wrong web.config

Tags: iis, web, config

I have 2 projects running on my IIS under Default Website, project A & B. They have two different physical paths.

When i try to run project A i get this error:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 27:     <pages>
Line 28:       <namespaces>
Line 29:         <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
Line 30:         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
Line 31:         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\B\EnrollmentPortal\Web.config    Line: 29
```

Project A tries to read the web.config of project B. How is this possible? I can't find any path from project A to project B, and no setting in IIS where you can specify a path to web.config.

How can i solve this?

Comment: I know its already very late, and you are not waiting for someone to answer here. But for others help, please mention the solution if you found.